# Can't install EclipseFP as scion-browser cannot be installed as terminfo cannot be installed

Tags: eclipse, haskell, ubuntu

Note: Question asked to Self Answer ( to save other's time)

Cannot install EclipseFP. This is because scion-browser cannot be installed. This is because terminfo cannot be installed, giving the following error:

"configure: error: curses headers could not be found, so this package cannot be built
"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note: Self Answer to save other's time.

1) Install the ncurses library and zlib1g libraries using:

```
apt-get install zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev
```

Source: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.agda/2684

2) Courtesy: http://eclipsefp.github.com/dev.html

> In the new Eclipse window that (hopefully) pops up, set the
>   location of the Scion server via Window > Preferences > Haskell >
>   Scion. If you installed it in a fairly standard location, the
>   Autodetect button should do the trick; otherwise, just Browse.

Comment: A note for the others: the bindings of the `scion-browser` of versions `<= 0.2.3` are broken. For it to install you'll firstly have to install `persistent-sqlite`, `persistent-template` and `persistent` of versions 0.6.x manually. Otherwise newer libs of `persistent` family will get installed, which the `scion-browser` is incompatible with, but doesn't have a proper restriction in bindings.

Comment: Yup!  Googling because stupid FP kept trying to install scion-browser and the rest.  This looks like it fixed that.