# Upgrade Cabal on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: cabal, ubuntu-14.04, cabal-install

When I install Haskell/GHC+cabal via `sudo apt-get` I installed cabal version 1.16.  This is obviously not the most up to date version.  How would I go about upgrade to at least version 1.18?  I tried doing `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Edit:

Also when I run `cabal install cabal-install` it appears to "install" version 1.20 but when I run `cabal -V` it says `cabal 1.16.0`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fixed it by adding the following line to my `~/.profile`: `export PATH=$(HOME)/.cabal/bin:$PATH`

Comment: I have the same problem but I changed this by editing the file manually and no changes, (I am a linux n00b)

Comment: @roundcrisis did you make sure to source your .profile after exporting it?

Comment: hi there, I made the necessary changes like this :D # set PATH so it includes cabal
if [ -d "$HOME/.cabal/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.cabal/bin:$PATH"
fi and it worked

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I changed `.profile` and ran `sudo apt-get` with `update`, `install cabal-install` and `upgrade cabal-install`, but `cabal - - version` still shows 1.16.