# Trying out "cabal sandbox init" and cabal not recognizing the command "sandbox"

Tags: haskell, sandbox, cabal

I'm trying out the tutorial about making a simple website with scotty but I get an error when I try the command "cabal sandbox init":

```
cabal: unrecognised command: sandbox (try --help)
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: what cabal version are you using? 18+?

Comment: cabal-install version 1.16.0.2
using version 1.16.0 of the Cabal library

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Is your Cabal/cabal-install version new enough? Sandboxes were introduced in Cabal 1.18. You can check the version with command `cabal --version`.

You might be able to upgrade with these commands:

```
cabal update
cabal install Cabal cabal-install
```

Comment: sorry for the dumb question

Comment: I ran these lines. I got a message like "cabal-install installed version 1.24". But when I run `cabal --version`, I still get `cabal 16.0.2`. Do you know what's going on ?

Comment: same problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826656/cabal-install-cabal-install-doesnt-update-cabal-version-in-osx)

Comment: Solution for Ubuntu [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25902613/upgrade-cabal-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Same problem with cabal-install 3.4.0.0 (archlinux)

Comment: @rambi: see [Haskell Cabal v2 and Sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58272366): *There are no sandboxes. You can install packages and they end up in the user's cabal store*