# Cabal claims it has updated itself but has not really

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

Following the instructions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27887249/trying-out-cabal-sandbox-init-and-cabal-not-recognizing-the-command-sandbox) on how to update `cabal-install`, I seemed to be able to install the latest version (or at least some version `> 1.18`, which is what I wanted.

```
$ cabal install Cabal cabal-install
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring cabal-install-1.22.6.0...
Building cabal-install-1.22.6.0...
Preprocessing executable 'cabal' for cabal-install-1.22.6.0...
<snip>
Linking dist/build/cabal/cabal ...
Installing executable(s) in /home/kavi/.cabal/bin
Installed cabal-install-1.22.6.0
```

However, when I tried `cabal sandbox`, it failed, so I checked `cabal --version`.

```
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.16.0.2
using version 1.16.0 of the Cabal library
```

As you can see, the version is not the one that cabal claimed to install.

Adding `~/.cabal/bin` to my path did nothing to help. (Yes, I did restart my terminal).

```
$ echo $PATH
<snip>:/home/kavi/.cabal/bin
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.16.0.2
using version 1.16.0 of the Cabal library
```

I tried restarting my computer, but still:

```
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.16.0.2
using version 1.16.0 of the Cabal library
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add `/home/kavi/.cabal/bin` to the beginning of the `$PATH`.

`which cabal` tells which executable shell will pick to execute, on my machine:

```
% echo $PATH
/Users/ogre/.local/bin:...

% which cabal
/Users/ogre/.local/bin/cabal
```

Comment: Ah, so having it at the end does nothing?

Comment: @k_g shell picks executable from the first directory it finds it in. The order matters, but in this cae you'd like to have `~/.cabal/bin` somewhere before system-wide directories.