# Haskell Cabal v2 and Sandbox

Tags: haskell, cabal

We are told that this is now legacy mode of cabal, to manage a user-defined sandbox:

```
cabal init sandbox
cabal install <some stuff>
```

Which is later loaded at your discretion using

```
cabal exec bash
```

**Question:** How is an equivalent operation performed using the new implementation of Cabal?

The documentation is (as it currently stands) very cryptic with zero usage example. That would be helpful to facilitate migration.

Currently contemplating Cabal 2.4.0.0 with GHC 8.6.5.

Comment: Did you really mean `cabal exec bash` and not... ghci or something else?

Comment: In my limited understanding, once I do `cabal exec bash`, the stuff in the sandbox become available everywhere in that bash session, whether I subsequently call ghc or ghci. And in the case where I use `ihaskell`, it is neither ghc nor ghci, so what would I `exec` for that?

Answer (score 2):

There are no sandboxes.  You can install packages and they end up in the user's cabal store using `v2-install` and `v2-install --lib`.  Let's use cabal to install a few packages:

```
cabal v2-udpate
cabal v2-install --lib generic-trie containers
```

Now we can load modules from these packages in GHCi:

```
ghci
> import Data.GenericTrie
> import Data.Map
```

Why does this work?  Because the `cabal v2-install --lib` modifies the default environment GHCi looks at to load packages.  This file is found at `.ghc/x86_64-linux-8.6.5/environments/default`.

You can delete the environment file any time to start mostly fresh.  This is handy if cabal is telling you some set of packages have conflicting dependencies with prior packages.  Think of it as a global store but as just pointers to the nix-style builds, so it's cheap to blow away and redo.

Comment: That's very interesting. So instead of nuking (repeatedly) the old cabal-sandbox, it seems I only deal with a simple file. Now I installed a couple of modules this way, and install was a success. Then I try to compile/interpret some programs, I get infinitely many `Could not load module ... It is a member of the hidden package`. Ok, so I need to manually add each and every module using the `cabal v2-install --lib` whenever I want to use it, even if it already is installed system-wide?? For the purpose of using Haskell to try stuff on one's system, that is nonsensical.

Comment: What workflow has you compiling or interpreting project that lack a build file?  If you repeatedly want things then use a `cabal.project` or `*.cabal` file.  If the project is small or even a toy then consider making a stand-alone `#!/usr/bin/env cabal` script.  Worthy of a separate question if your workflow is still painful.

Comment: I was not aware that to be a seasoned software engineer is a necessary condition to use Haskell (I see that some people work very hard to make the language unusable to as many people as possible). I don't have a clue what is a "stand-alone cabal script" nor what it is intended to do.

Comment: @p_barill, that is a valid criticism. In my experience, it's actually possible to go *further* in Haskell than most other modern language environments without really understanding its build tools. But pretty soon, you really do need to learn the basics of `cabal` if you want to get things done without pulling your hair out. A side question to Thomas M. DuBuisson: is there an easy way to start a GHCi session on a particular module in a project? `cabal new-repl` seems to start in whatever module(s) it feels like.

Comment: @dfeuer What I'm looking for is something similar to `virtualenv` in python. It's simple, it's lean and it's fast. And I believe it is documented, unlike Cabal where it's documentation is meaningless techno-babble. The old behavior of cabal was the closest to this I saw. Why there is no such simple tool in Haskell is beyond my understanding.

Comment: @p_barill I still am not clear what is needed, which is why I suggested a separate question.  You can use environments in Haskell much like virtualenv in Python (I think, I've not used that much).  You install with a named environment then use that environment `cabal v2-install --package-env myenv --lib <packages> ; ghci -package-env myenv` and `import <module>`.  Feel free to ask a question on the cabal specifics and @ me as desired.

Comment: @dfeuer No, there is actually an underlying GHC issue one could hunt down that prevents all the modules from being loaded by default.  You do have to `cabal v2-repl [project]` and `import <module>`.

Comment: Having to import the needed module is annoying enough. Having to unload whatever it happened to pick for me is much more maddening.

Comment: @dfeuer It sounds like you want `cabal v2-exec ghci` which means cabal is passing the environment for the cabal project to ghci.

Comment: I've had extremely mixed results with that, though I can't say off the top of my head what problems I've encountered.

Comment: I used to use cabal v1 commands and the sandbox to cache the builds in CI/CD. This was located in `.cabal-sandbox`. Now with v2 commands, the cache is located somewhere else, where should I be caching the builds for my CI/CD for v2 commands?