# how to manage cabal sandboxes

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install, cabal-sandbox

The [current documentation](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html?highlight=sandbox#sandboxes-basic-usage) of cabal shows a `sandbox` subcommand.

The [respective page on github](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/blob/master/Cabal/doc/installing-packages.rst) no longer contains the section on sandboxes.

I'm using cabal version 3.2.0.0, but the `sandbox` subcommand is absent. What is the correct way to manage sandboxes with cabal?

Apparently there's an [overhaul](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/pull/6613) going on with the documentation, there's mention of a [Nix-style/new-/v2 commands](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/nix-local-build-overview.html#nix-style-local-builds) but it's unclear to a noob what's the canonical way of using sandboxes with cabal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They're no longer needed. The nix-style store does everything sandboxes did, but better. Just use use `cabal build` (`cabal v2-build` for pre-3.0 cabal's) and other `cabal` commands with impunity in a bare, sandbox-free directory.

Comment: Thanks, @Daniel, but how do I get the equivalent of a sandbox, i.e. a self-contained Haskell environment akin to a python venv?

Comment: @BernhardWagner To answer that properly, we'd need to know why you want one.  What need do you have that isn't handled by v2-style installs?

Comment: @BernhardWagner All packages are built in a self-contained Haskell environment. (Or: what observations do you make that causes you to believe you do not already have a self-contained environment?)

Comment: @BernhardWagner cabal >= 3 can store multiple versions of each library in a shared central store (previously, conflicts could arise when you did that, so separate sandboxes were added as an stopgap measure). When you are developing a package and invoke `cabal build`, your build process sees a "view" of the store that fits the `build-depends` in your cabal file. You don't need sandboxes, and you don't need to "cabal install" your dependencies individually: everything is handled by the `cabal build`. You might need to run `cabal update` once in a while to refresh the list of available packages.

Comment: I understood that basically whenever I develop a haskell project within a directory, it's in a sandbox by default.
Python's venv in addition refers to a specific python version. Is that supported with cabal as well?

Comment: In the meantime I've found another post on stackoverflow dealing with a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58272366/haskell-cabal-v2-and-sandbox

Comment: @BernhardWagner You can ask for a specific compiler per-command with `-w`, or use `cabal configure` (still with `-w`) to use a specific compiler by default for future commands that don't have a `-w` flag.